# How do I sync data from a database to a combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, sqlconnection, sqldataadapter

I'm creating a form of which I have to show the data from a database into a combo box and I need help to do it, please

I have already tried to download MySql Server, however, it only supports up to Visual Studio 2017 and I have Visual Studio 2019

```cs
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Code\C#\MyFirstUI\MyFirstUI\LOGIN.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    try
    {
        string query = "select USERNAME from LOGIN";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Username");
        comboBox3.DisplayMember = "Userame";
        comboBox3.DataSource = ds.Tables["Username"];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // write exception info to log or anything else
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error occured!");
    }
}
```

I would have expected the data from the database however, I got an output of nothing

Comment: `comboBox3.DisplayMember = "Username";`  You are missing the "n".

Comment: Oh I'm going to see if it works after

Comment: Sadly, there is no difference

Comment: Well, use the debugger.  Put a stop on that DataSource line and inspect that DataTable when the program stops there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set `comboBox3.ValueMember="USERNAME"` and `comboBox3.DisplayMember="USERNAME"` ,  Use "USERNAME", not "Userame", because your sql is `select USERNAME`
2. Check if `ds.Tables["Username"].Rows.Count>0`